# How does JPA's merge and persist methods work internally?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Well, I have the following question, when we use jpa and modify the state of our table, either with a persist or merge for example, we need to have a managed instance, when I use the persit method for example, internally the implementation will manage first the object and then put it in the database, or first put it in the database and then put it as a managed instance? I ask this, because I want to know if every operation that is done in the database has to be managed, or is the operation performed first and then managed? For example, when we give an entityManager.merge(object), will the merge first put the information in the database, and then return a managed instance, or does it simply put it as a managed instance first?

Comment: I would recommend reading this two articles https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/  https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/

Comment: The articles are very good, but I want to know implementation details and in the articles it doesn't speak, I want to know first if an object is persisted in the database, or first the object is managed and then it is persisted @DavideD'Alto

Comment: There are so many use cases to spell out for each that affect things that this question isn't one that belongs here. Most providers will delay inserts/updates until a flush is required - so what you get back may not have resulted in anything being done in the database. Best to turn on logging and see what happens and when, and even to look at your provider's code. Every Entity instance you call persist/merge/find on will be managed, so changes made to them are tracked and synchronized to the database on flush/commit calls.